# Qt: When shall I use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE?

Tags: c++, qt

The documentation said I need to Q_DECLARE_METATYPE a custom structure so it will work properly in a signal-slot.

But I have tried the following code which seems working fine?

```
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
struct MyStruct
{
        int a;
        int b;
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

signals:
    void test(MyStruct);

public slots:
    void tested(MyStruct);
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
};

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
//------------------------CPP-------------------------------
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(test(MyStruct)),this,SLOT(tested(MyStruct)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::tested(MyStruct t)
{
    qDebug()<<t.a<<t.b;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    MyStruct t;
    t.a=1;
    t.b=2;
    emit test(t);
}
```

The signal slot works without any problem, but in the following case:

```
struct SoundType 
{
    enum Type
    {
        Bip = 0,
        LowBatt, 
        LowSat,
        FarAway,
        LostLink
    };
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(SoundType::Type)
```

it seems I do have to call the declaration inorder to use

> SoundType::Type

in signal slot.

so in what case do I have to use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE in order to use a signal slot?

Comment: The docs state: [*Declare new types with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() to make them available to QVariant and other template-based functions*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#details). I'm curious, where in the docs did you find that you have to use it when using custom structures in signals/slots?

Comment: Here: doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/custom-types.html, or in the Qt5 there is no need to do this any more? Or it is just for queued signals?

Comment: Using custom types in direct signal-slot calls without `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` has worked for as long as I can remember. I'm not sure what that part of the docs is trying to tell.

Comment: @Nyaruko only needed for queued connections, direct connections don't need to wrap signal arguments in `QVariant`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with signals and slots. `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` needs to be used when you want to be able to store your own type in a `QVariant`

Note that this macro requires the type to be fully defined at the point where it is used; for pointer types, the pointer as well must be fully defined, so ideally you should place the macro right after your class declaration (once again, you only need it if you want to store your type objects in a `QVariant`).

Comment: @Nyaruko, If you had any errors on signals and slots before you added `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`, then it is just a coincidence. Using enumerations in signals is no different than using classes.

Answer (score 5):

> When shall I use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE?

**Always when the type is used with either signals/slots or `QVariant`**.

Your test case is incomplete: it'll break as soon as you move one of the connected objects to a different thread.

You may also need to `qRegisterMetatype<YourType>()` e.g. in `main`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience, to register custom enumerations in Qt Meta Object System you would need to mark the enum using `Q_ENUM` inside its scope, for example:

```
struct SoundType 
{
    enum Type
    {
        Bip = 0,
        LowBatt, 
        LowSat,
        FarAway,
        LostLink
    };
    Q_ENUM(Type);
};
```

This would enable us to use the enum in QML for example (although the parent type would have to be registered in QML first). In many cases though, including in Qt itself (`QAbstractItemModel::data(..., int role)` for example), it is more convenient to use plain `int` instead.

There are others macros too. In general, custom structure which doesn't derive from `QObject` can be registered by typing `Q_GADGET` at the beginning of the structure (just like `Q_OBJECT` macro). Note that such structure must not have signals or slots, but it can register properties using `Q_PROPERTY` as usual (albeit without notification signal).

`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`, as pointed out by @SingerOfTheFall, would register template based type into `QVariant` (so it can be retrieved using `qvariant_cast<T>()`).

Some structure need to be registered to be queued in asynchronous signals using `qRegisterMetaType<T>(name)`, such as signal which passes `QVector<int>`.